# SwiftUI button action with no text content

Tags: swiftui

I have two buttons next to each other. One is for starting a recording, one is for playing. When I click the play button, I see "play clicked" logged. When I click the record button, nothing happens. When I add a letter to the record button text, it's logged just fine.

Why can't I use a button with empty text in SwiftUI?

```swift
Button(action: {
    print("record clicked")
}) {
    Text("")
}
.frame(width: 55, height: 55)
.background(Color.red)
.cornerRadius(9999)

Button(action: {
    print("play clicked")
}) {
    Image(systemName: "play")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(.system(size: 30))
}
.frame(width: 55, height: 55)
.background(Color.green)
.cornerRadius(9999)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They determine tappable area for button by label content, but it is almost zero for empty text, so just make it remarkable, like

```
Button(action: {
    print("record clicked")
}) {
    Text("")
        .padding()     // << this !!
}
```

Tested as worked with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

Comment: doesn't work for me.